# Amazon RDS - Slow queries at every minute change

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-rds, mysql-slow-query-log

We recently noticed that we have a lot more records in our slow query log at every minute change (at around second 0 of every minute). This didn't seem to be related to any of our cronjobs so I decided to do a quick test on a new RDS t3.micro instance with MySQL 8.0.23.

Here are the steps to replicate:

1. Create a table:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE `_test` (
      `date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `val` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    COMMIT;
   ```
2. Make 100'000 inserts (important: use a single query for each row, do not insert multiple rows with one query), like:

   ```
    INSERT INTO `_test` (`date`, `val`) VALUES (NOW(), '1');
    INSERT INTO `_test` (`date`, `val`) VALUES (NOW(), '1');
    INSERT INTO `_test` (`date`, `val`) VALUES (NOW(), '1');
    ...
   ```
3. Run the following query:

   ```
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(`date`, -2, 2) AS `second`, AVG(`count`) AS `avg`
      FROM  
        ( SELECT  `date`, COUNT(1) AS `count`
            FROM  `_test`
            GROUP BY  `date`
        ) AS `temp`
      GROUP BY  `second`
      ORDER BY  `avg` ASC
   ```

My results were:

| second | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | 20.1935 |
| 34 | 50.9667 |
| 01 | 51.1613 |
| 26 | 52.6667 |
| 02 | 52.9032 |
| 50 | 53.5333 |
| 20 | 53.6667 |
| 59 | 53.7188 |
| 30 | 53.8333 |
| 06 | 54.1613 |
| 36 | 54.1667 |
| 27 | 54.3333 |
| 05 | 54.5161 |
| 52 | 54.7742 |
| 04 | 55.0968 |
| 35 | 55.7000 |
| 15 | 55.9000 |
| 07 | 56.0000 |
| 38 | 56.0000 |
| 19 | 56.1000 |
| 49 | 56.1333 |
| 11 | 56.1333 |
| 29 | 56.1667 |
| 45 | 56.2000 |
| 03 | 56.2258 |

The inserts usually took about 0.02 seconds (50-56 inserts per second on average), except for second 0, where the inserts took 0.05 seconds (only 20 inserts per second on average).

And the lag seems to get bigger with bigger and more complex tables and/or queries with joins. Any idea what may be causing this lag at second 0?

**EDIT:**

Additional information for @Rick James.

```
    CREATE TABLE `rds_history` (
     `action_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `called_by_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `action` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `mysql_version` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `master_host` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `master_port` int DEFAULT NULL,
     `master_user` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
     `master_log_file` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `master_log_pos` mediumtext,
     `master_ssl` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `master_delay` int DEFAULT NULL,
     `auto_position` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `master_gtid` text
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

    CREATE TABLE `rds_replication_status` (
     `action_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `called_by_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `action` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `mysql_version` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `master_host` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `master_port` int DEFAULT NULL,
     `replication_log_file` text,
     `replication_stop_point` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
     `replication_gtid` text
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rds_configuration | InnoDB | 10 | Compact | 3 | 5461 | 16384 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 08.03.21 11:19 | NULL | NULL | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL |  |  |
| rds_global_status_history | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 0 | 0 | 16384 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 08.03.21 11:19 | NULL | NULL | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL |  |  |
| rds_global_status_history_old | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 0 | 0 | 16384 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 08.03.21 11:19 | NULL | NULL | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL |  |  |
| rds_heartbeat2 | InnoDB | 10 | Compact | 0 | 0 | 16384 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 08.03.21 11:19 | 26.10.21 20:03 | NULL | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL |  |  |
| rds_history | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 1 | 16384 | 16384 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 08.03.21 11:19 | NULL | NULL | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL |  |  |
| rds_replication_status | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 1 | 16384 | 16384 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 08.03.21 11:19 | NULL | NULL | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL |  |  |
| rds_sysinfo | InnoDB | 10 | Compact | 0 | 0 | 16384 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | 08.03.21 11:19 | NULL | NULL | utf8_general_ci | NULL |  |  |

**UPDATE:**

Just did the same test on a brand new RDS t3.micro instance running **MySQL 5.7.34** (default:mysql-5-7 option and parameter group). Similar results:

| second | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | 25.8286 |
| 01 | 44.8857 |
| 30 | 45.0000 |
| 22 | 45.8235 |
| 55 | 46.2857 |
| 20 | 46.8286 |
| 15 | 46.9143 |
| 51 | 47.1143 |
| 02 | 47.3714 |
| 45 | 47.5294 |
| 54 | 47.6286 |
| 25 | 47.6471 |
| 50 | 47.6571 |
| 24 | 47.6765 |
| 21 | 47.7647 |
| 10 | 47.7714 |
| 56 | 47.9714 |
| 16 | 48.1143 |
| 43 | 48.1176 |
| 47 | 48.1429 |
| 23 | 48.2353 |
| 07 | 48.2571 |
| 35 | 48.2647 |
| 57 | 48.3714 |
| 53 | 48.4571 |
| 06 | 48.4857 |
| 59 | 48.5429 |
| 05 | 48.8571 |
| 36 | 49.0588 |
| 03 | 49.1429 |
| 46 | 49.1471 |
| 52 | 49.1714 |
| 48 | 49.1714 |
| 26 | 49.1765 |
| 11 | 49.2000 |
| 31 | 49.2059 |
| 40 | 49.2059 |
| 58 | 49.2286 |
| 49 | 49.2857 |
| 39 | 49.2941 |
| 12 | 49.3429 |
| 04 | 49.3714 |
| 19 | 49.4000 |
| 34 | 49.4118 |
| 08 | 49.4286 |
| 38 | 49.4412 |
| 33 | 49.4706 |
| 17 | 49.5429 |
| 09 | 49.5714 |
| 18 | 49.6286 |
| 32 | 49.6765 |
| 27 | 49.8235 |
| 13 | 49.8286 |
| 41 | 49.8529 |
| 29 | 49.8529 |
| 37 | 49.8824 |
| 14 | 49.8857 |
| 44 | 50.0000 |
| 28 | 50.0588 |
| 42 | 50.0882 |

Since I wasn't able to replicate the results on my local machine and on a dedicated server (both running MySQL 5.7), this must be an Amazon RDS related problem rather than a MySQL version problem.

I asked Amazon to look into this and do the same test, no response. Their support hasn't been very helpful in general so far. Is anyone else here with an AWS account able to replicate and confirm the results above? I can not believe we are the only ones affected by this.

Comment: Do you see the same issue with a "non-burstable" instance type?

Comment: Change `long_query_time` to `0`; run for a few minutes before changing that setting back.  (Need to run your script.)  Then the slowlog may show the culprit.  It could be a monitoring task like `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.  Please report back; this could be an interesting thing to note.  Also, what is the version number of RDS-MySQL that is running?

Comment: @Parsifal, yes, we first noticed this on our production m3.medium instance.

Comment: @Rick James, we enabled general_log to record all queries and Amazon (rdsadmin) is indeed running some queries at or close to second 0. We opened a support ticket a few days ago. Their answer was "Please note that being that RDS is a managed service, the rdsadmin user queries the database to check the health of the database. However, it is very unusual for these queries to have an impact on the performance of your queries as the user only would query system tables and processes as observed in the queries provided". MySQL version is 8.0.23.

Comment: @Simon - For my understanding, please provide the queries that they are running every minute.  _Any_ query has _some_ impact on _all_ other queries running.  After all, there is a single server (`mysqld`) doing all the work.  (When I get the list, I can go into more details.)

Comment: @Rick James, out of the 230 minutes general_log was on, the following query ran 159 times at exactly second 0: ```SELECT count(*) FROM mysql.rds_history WHERE action = 'disable set master' GROUP BY action_timestamp, called_by_user, action, mysql_version, master_host, master_port, master_user, master_log_file, master_log_pos, master_ssl ORDER BY action_timestamp LIMIT 1```

Comment: @Rick James, an this one ran 133 times ```SELECT count(*) FROM mysql.rds_replication_status WHERE master_host IS NOT NULL AND master_port IS NOT NULL GROUP BY action_timestamp, called_by_user, action, mysql_version, master_host, master_port ORDER BY action_timestamp LIMIT 1```

Comment: Can you provide me with `SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.rds_history` and the other table?  And  `USE mysql; SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'rds%';`

Comment: I've updated the original post with those information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since RDS is using block storage (EBS), changes to an RDS database are limited by the IOPS of the storage you choose. General purpose SSD storage comes with 3 IOPS per GB, so you have a limit of 60 IOPS with 20 GB, for example. Now if you use more then the provisioned 60 IOPS, your experiencing a delay at the end of every minute (or the beginning of the new minute).

**Solution**: Either increase storage (attention, general purpose SSD [gp2] is limited to a throughput of max 250 MiB/s and, thus, capable of max 1'000 IOPS, even if you increase storage to more than 333 GB) or choose IOPS-SSD storage, which supports higher numbers of IOPS.

Answer (score 0):

(Not yet a complete answer.)

These are strange queries:

```
SELECT  count(*)
    FROM  mysql.rds_history
    WHERE  action = 'disable set master'
    GROUP BY  action_timestamp, called_by_user, action, mysql_version,
        master_host, master_port, master_user, master_log_file,
        master_log_pos, master_ssl
    ORDER BY  action_timestamp
    LIMIT  1

SELECT  count(*)
    FROM  mysql.rds_replication_status
    WHERE  master_host IS NOT NULL
      AND  master_port IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY  action_timestamp, called_by_user, action, mysql_version,
        master_host, master_port
    ORDER BY  action_timestamp
    LIMIT  1
```

The combination of `COUNT(*)` without any other columns, plus `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` is, in my opinion, nonsense.

Comment: Agreed. Those queries do not make much sense at all. Furthermore, both tables only have one row. But I also agree with Amazon: I don't see how they would stall other queries.

Comment: @Simon - And those tables do not have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  Ugh!  Suggest you file some kind of bug report with RDS.  (I don't have an account, so I would probably be ignored.)

Comment: Absolutely. Although I don't think those queries are the reason for the lag. I have absolutely no idea what other processes Amazon is running on their RDS instances, but this must be related to Amazon, not to the MySQL version (see my latest update to my post).